# Finding stream function from potential

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a velocity potential (ie the gradient of this function gives the velocity) given by :

$$\phi(x,y) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{(y-1)^2 + x^2}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{(y+1)^2 + x^2}} + k x$$

where $k$ = constant. I would like to find the corresponding stream function $\psi(x,y)$ so that 
$\psi(x,y)$ = constant on streamlines. Another way to state this is to say , find $\psi(x,y)$ such that :

$$\psi_x = \phi_y \text{ and } \psi_y = -\phi_x$$

where subscripts denote the partial derivative. Is there a way to find $\psi(x,y)$

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You are going to have trouble here because this is not a legitimate velocity potential. The gradient has singularities (infinite velocities) at two points in the plane.  Clearly this potential does not satisfy Laplace's equation.

You would have a similar problem with the function

$$\phi(x,y) = \frac1{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$

In polar coordinates

$$\phi(r,\theta)= \frac1{r},\\ \nabla^2\phi=\frac1{r^3}\neq0.$$

Hence, there is no point in the plane where the continuity equation is satisfied since

$$\nabla \cdot \mathbf{u}= \nabla^2\phi \neq 0.$$

It is not possible to find $\psi$ through indefinite integration

$$\psi(x,y) = -\int\phi_x\,dy+ A(x),\\\psi(x,y) = \int\phi_y\,dx+ B(y).$$

Comment: This may not be a knock-down objection: physically, such a flow corresponds to a vortex at that point ( note that the equipotential lines are circular.) in other words, a stream function which is analytic except at a few points isn't necessarily wrong.

Comment: A line vortex has stream function $\ln(r)$ which satisfies Laplace's equation.

Comment: The potential of a vortex is $-C\theta$ which also satisfies Laplace's equation.

Comment: The potential of a sink flow is $C\ln(r)$ -- also satisfying Laplace's equation.

Comment: Good point. Odd.

Comment: Given that the flow isn't incompressible (due to $\nabla\cdot \mathbf{u}=0$), it does seem strange to look for a stream function. (I think one can still work in that formalism only if one incorporates the density $\rho(x,y)$ as well.)